# Enabling implicit conversion from `vector<const T>&` to `const vector<T>&`

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, constants, implicit-conversion

Suppose we define a class `template<typename T> class vector` that behaves like `std::vector` except that we are able to alter its class definition.

Suppose also that we have a function `f(const vector<T>&)`.

How can we enable an implicit conversion that would allow us to pass a `vector<const T>&` into `f`?

---

I think such an implicit conversion is sensible, because I believe the restrictions imposed by the `const vector<T>&` are a superset of the restrictions imposed by the `vector<const T>&`. But any guidance that might be enlightening would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you'd also want the opposite conversion to work?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, because a `vector` can be modified in more ways than overwriting/modifying individual elements. So I think `const vector<T>` is more restricted than `vector<const T>`.

Comment: `std::vector<const T>` is a very limited type. Prior to C++11 it is ill-formed, and afterward you can't add elements

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that `f` is indeed a *function* for some concrete `T`, as opposed to a function template (i.e. `template<typename T> f(vector<T> const&)`), then the following operator inside of `vector<T>` should work:

```
template<typename U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<U>{}>>
operator vector<std::remove_const_t<U>>() const {
    // ...
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225c8e7715c9a63f)**</kbd>

However, `f` cannot be a standalone function template as its `T` will simply be deduced to be itself `const` and no conversion will take place. Overloading can solve this, but will be ugly.

N.b. this is presumably just making a copy of the elements inside of the original `vector`; returning a `vector<T> const&` that somehow aliases the internals of the original `vector<T const>` is a significantly different task, as it would involve extra lifetime-management state and/or questionably-legal type aliasing.

Comment: Given that we're implementing the `vector<T>`, we'd be in a position to declare that the converted array is a *view* on the original, and therefore only valid until its source vector changes.  That would solve the lifetime management, I think.

Comment: @Toby : It's all very hypothetical... Does this imagined `vector` use the standard library's allocator model? If so, removing `const`ness is playing with fire UB-wise; and if not, well, we could change _all sorts_ of things for our convenience. ;-]

Comment: I think it's safe because we never expose a non-const `T&`.  But it's looking pretty hard to shoehorn into a single `vector` class rather than a separate view class.  And as you say, it's completely speculative at this point.  I'm happy not to think about it any further.